# Maximum difference between sum of even and odd position elements: How to memoize the brute-force approach?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, backtracking, memoization

I have the following code for a problem.

**The problem is:** *Maximize the absolute difference between the sum of elements at the even and odd positions of an array.* *To do so, you may delete as many elements you want.*

I did it by brute-force by using backtracking. My logic is that, for each index I have 2 options: 
a) either delete it (in this case, I put it in  a set) 
b) don't delete it (in this case, I removed the index from the set and backtracked). 
I took the local maximum of two cases and updated the global maximum value appropriately.

```cpp
void maxAns(vector<int> &arr, int index, set<int> &removed, int &res)
{
    if (index<0)
        return;
    int k=0;
    int s3=0,s4=0;
    for (int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
    {
        if (i!=index)
        {
            set<int>::iterator it=removed.find(i);
            if (it==removed.end())
            {
                if( k%2==0)
                    s3+=arr[i];
                else
                    s4+=arr[i];
                k++;
            }
        }
        else    //don't delete the element
        {
            if (k%2==0)
                s3+=arr[i];
            else
                s4+=arr[i];
            k++;
        }
    }

    k=0;
    int s1=0, s2=0;
    for (int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
    {
        if (i!=index)
        {
            set<int>::iterator it=removed.find(i);
            if (it==removed.end())
            {
                if (k%2==0)
                    s1+=arr[i];
                else
                    s2+=arr[i];
                k++;
            }
        }
        else    //delete the element
        {
            //add index into the removed set
            removed.insert(index);
        }
    }

    //delete the index element
    int t1=abs(s1-s2);
    maxAns(arr,index-1,removed,res);

    //don't delete the index element, and then backtrack
    set<int>::iterator itr=removed.find(index);
    removed.erase(itr);

    int t2=abs(s3-s4);
    maxAns(arr,index-1,removed,res);

    //choose the max value
    res=max(res,max(t1,t2));
}
```

Please suggest how to memoize this solution as I think it's quite inefficient. Feel free to share any interesting approach.

Comment: I'd probably delete from the back and work forward. That way changes in your subproblems do not keep changing the later steps.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Can you elaborate a bit more? I am also deleting from the back in above approach (index is initially the index of the last element of the array).

Comment: what do you mean by memorising? You can always save that function in another file an use it when necessary. If you meant like recording the behaviour i would need an extra information, what is your function base, what are elements you want to change etc?

Comment: Sorry, I just looked at the first loop, which was going forward. For Danilo, "memo - izing" is a technique of remembering what you've done so you don't recompute the same smaller problem over and over.

Comment: My thoughts on memoization for the last N numbers is to store (N, even-sum, odd-sum) I don't think you care at this point which ones were deleted, because if you delete something before that memo, you just swap odd-sum and even-sum.

Comment: But I see that you do want that in the final output, so maybe add a bitmask with N bits (too bad bitset won't work here). Although if you stick with recursion you might be able to rebuild that on the returns, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: divide and conquer. Consider that a fixed length list as a left part of a larger list, maximised (or minimised) for the actual, rather than abdolute difference and depending on the parity of its length, would pair better with a right part that does not depend on the parity of its length.

```
[0,3] ++ [0,3]    -> diff -3 -3 = -6
[0,3] ++ [9,13,1] -> diff -3 -3 = -6
```

We can also easily create base cases for `max_actual_diff` and `min_actual_diff` of lists with lengths 1 and 2. Note that the best choice for those might include ommiting one or more of those few elements.

JavaScript code:

```js
function max_diff(A, el, er, memo){
  if (memo[['mx', el, er]])
    return memo[['mx', el, er]]
  
  if (er == el)
    return memo[['mx', el, er]] = [A[el], 1, 0, 0]

  var best = [A[el], 1, 0, 0]
  
  if (er == el + 1){
    if (A[el] - A[er] > best[2]){
      best[2] = A[el] - A[er]
      best[3] = 2
    }
    if (A[er] > best[0]){
      best[0] = A[er]
      best[1] = 1
    }
    
    return memo[['mx', el, er]] = best
  }
  
  const mid = el + ((er - el) >> 1)

  const left = max_diff(A, el, mid, memo)
  const right_min = min_diff(A, mid + 1, er, memo)
  const right_max = max_diff(A, mid + 1, er, memo)
  
  // Best odd = odd + even
  if (left[0] - right_min[2] > best[0]){
    best[0] = left[0] - right_min[2]
    best[1] = left[1] + right_min[3]
  }
  // Best odd = even + odd
  if (left[2] + right_max[0] > best[0]){
    best[0] = left[2] + right_max[0]
    best[1] = left[3] + right_max[1]
  }
  
  // Best even = odd + odd
  if (left[0] - right_min[0] > best[2]){
    best[2] = left[0] - right_min[0]
    best[3] = left[1] + right_min[1]
  }
  // Best even = even + even
  if (left[2] + right_max[2] > best[2]){
    best[2] = left[2] + right_max[2]
    best[3] = left[3] + right_max[3]
  }
    
  return memo[['mx', el, er]] = best
}

function min_diff(A, el, er, memo){
  if (memo[['mn', el, er]])
    return memo[['mn', el, er]]
  
  if (er == el)
    return memo[['mn', el, er]] = [A[el], 1, 0, 0]

  var best = [A[el], 1, 0, 0]
  
  if (er == el + 1){
    if (A[el] - A[er] < best[2]){
      best[2] = A[el] - A[er]
      best[3] = 2
    }
    if (A[er] < best[0]){
      best[0] = A[er]
      best[1] = 1
    }
    
    return memo[['mn', el, er]] = best
  }
  
  const mid = el + ((er - el) >> 1)

  const left = min_diff(A, el, mid, memo)
  const right_min = min_diff(A, mid + 1, er, memo)
  const right_max = max_diff(A, mid + 1, er, memo)
  
  // Best odd = odd + even
  if (left[0] - right_max[2] < best[0]){
    best[0] = left[0] - right_max[2]
    best[1] = left[1] + right_max[3]
  }
  // Best odd = even + odd
  if (left[2] + right_min[0] < best[0]){
    best[0] = left[2] + right_min[0]
    best[1] = left[3] + right_min[1]
  }
  
  // Best even = odd + odd
  if (left[0] - right_max[0] < best[2]){
    best[2] = left[0] - right_max[0]
    best[3] = left[1] + right_max[1]
  }
  // Best even = even + even
  if (left[2] + right_min[2] < best[2]){
    best[2] = left[2] + right_min[2]
    best[3] = left[3] + right_min[3]
  }
    
  return memo[['mn', el, er]] = best
}


var memo = {}

var A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(`A: ${ JSON.stringify(A) }`)
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(max_diff(A, 0, A.length-1, memo)) + ' // [odd max, len, even max, len]')
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(min_diff(A, 0, A.length-1, memo)) + ' // [odd min, len, even min, len]')
console.log('\nmemo:\n' + JSON.stringify(memo))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maximize the absolute difference between the sum of elements at the odd and even positions of an array. To do so, you may delete as many elements as you want.

**Example**

1. A = [9, 5, 2, 9, 4]

Ans = 16    =>  [9, 2, 9] = 9-2+9

2. A = [8, 6, 2, 7, 7, 2, 7]

Ans = 18    => [8, 2, 7, 2, 7] = 8-2+7-2+7

**Hint:**

- At the position **"i+1"**, Let the maximum and minimum possible difference for all the subsequences of subarray A[i+1,n] be Max, Min respectively
- Hence at position **"i"**, the maximum and minimum possible difference for all the subsequences of subarray A[i, n] can be calculated as

1. Include the current element arr[i]
2. Don't Include the current element arr[I]

```
Max = MAX(Max, arr[i] - Min) 
Min = MIN(Min, arr[i] - Max)
```

**Explanation:**

```
A      =   9, 5, 2, 9, 4 
Max    =  16, 12, 9, 9, 4 
Min    =  -7, -7, -7, 0, 0
```

Final Answer: `Max(Max[0], Min[0]) = Max(16, -7) = 16`

**Time Complexity:** O(n)

**Space Complexity:** O(1) * As Just 2 variables Max, Min were used*

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we always add the values at even positions and we always rest the values at odd positions. Now, we will iterate from 1 to n and make choices: keep the element or delete it; the thing is that when we keep an element, we need to know if it is at an even position or an odd position, so we will do Dynamic Programming:
[][0]dp[i][0]: max possible sum using the elements in 1,2,…,a1,a2,…,ai and the resulting array is of even length.
[][1]dp[i][1]: same as above, but now the resulting array is of odd length.
Transitions are: keep it or delete it.
[][]=max([−1][],[−1][!]+[]∗((==0)?1:−1)dp[i][r]=max(dp[i−1][r],dp[i−1][!r]+a[i]∗((r==0)?1:−1);
Now it's when someone says: Wait minute, you are always adding at even positions and resting at odd positions, what if it's of the other way. Well, for this, perform again the DP but adding at odd positions and resting at even positions. You stay with the maximum of both solutions